# In Java, How to implement the functions similar to using the template parameter to avoid creating Creator subclasses in C++?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-method

Recently, when I was reading the book named "Design Pattern-Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software", there was such a paragraph in the book:

> Using templates to avoid subclassing. As we've mentioned, another potential
>   problem with factory methods is that they might force you to subclass just
>   to create the appropriate Product objects. Another way to get around this in
>   C++ is to provide a template subclass of Creator that's parameterized by the
>   Product class.

what I want to know is: In Java, How to implement the functions similar to using the template parameter to avoid creating Creator subclasses in C++?

I have tried to use generics, but I don't know how to use it.

```
public class ConcreteCreator<T extends Product> extends Creator{

    @Override
    public Product createProduct() {
        // ... how can I return new T();

    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it directly as You mentioned (@GhostCat explained it in detail). But generally, if You need to do it this way, there is a big chance that Your class structure was wrongly designed or uses some anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, there is already a generic type for factory methods.  It's `Supplier<T>`.

You should probably use `Supplier<Product>` instead of your `Creator`.

Then, you typically use a lambda function or method reference to supply an instance.

If you want to call `setCreator(Supplier<Product>)`, for example, and you want it to create your `MyProduct` subclass, then you just call `setCreator(MyProduct::new)`.

Lambdas allow you to do more complex constructions without subclassing, even when an appropriate constructor doesn't exist, like `setCreator(() -> new MyProduct(CONST_VAL_1, UtilityClass.getCurrentValue2());`

Answer (score 2):

> // ... how can I return new T();

Simple answer: you can't that easily in Java.

Java isn't C++, and generics are in many ways less powerful than C++ templates.

The point is: there is no way to "generically" create new objects of some unknown arbitrary class. You might be able to *work around* that by using reflection, and `Class.forName()` and `newInstance()`, but that comes at the usual cost of reflection: it is clumsy and errorprone.

Sure, you can return a specific subclass type (and instance there), but then you have to write a specific method for each such type.

Answer (score 1):

You can not instantiate `T`. It is a placeholder which will be erased on run time. Instead of returning the `Product` you want to return the concrete type of `Product`.